# Nonunit element in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

If $a+bi$ is not a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ prove that $a^2+b^2>1$.

*Definition:* Let $R$ be commutative ring with unit element. An element $u\in R$ we call unit if it's inverse $u^{-1}$ also lies in $R$.

**Proof:** Suppose by contradiction that $a^2+b^2\leq 1$ then $a^2+b^2\in \{0,1\}$.

If $a^2+b^2=1$ then we have four cases $a+bi\in \{\pm i, \pm 1\}$. But each of them is unit of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. In this case we get contradiction.

If $a^2+b^2=0$ then $a+bi=0$. Here we have no contradiction, since by definition $0$ is NOT unit.

Can anyone explain this to me, please?

Comment: Explanation: The problem poser accidentally forgot to exclude zero.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Do you mean that we should add a nonzero element in the definition of unit element?

Comment: $0$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ that fails $a^2+b^2>1$.  Therefore, the problem should state that "If $a+bi\not=0$ is not a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $a^2+b^2>1$."  Alternately, "If $a+bi$ is not a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $a+bi=0$ or $a^2+b^2>1$."

Comment: @MichaelBurr, Indeed, but I am proving via contradiction. I am supposing that $a^2+b^2\leq 1$. And the case when it is equal to zero confuses me. Because in this case we get $a=b=0$.

Comment: The original problem is wrong - another condition is needed.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, Thanks a lot! I got what you mean!

Answer (score 1):

In general, for a number field $K$ we have that $|Nm(\alpha)|>1$ for every (nonzero) non-unit $\alpha\in \mathcal{O}_K$, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798883/why-is-1-textnm-k-bbbq-beta-textnm-k-bbbq-alpha/2798919#2798919).
Now $Nm(\alpha)=a^2+b^2$ for $K=\Bbb{Q}[i]$, and $\mathcal{O}_K=\Bbb{Z}[i]$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a+ib$ is unit so there exists $c+id\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $(a+ib)(c+id)=1$ hence  $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=1$ then $a^2+b^2=1$. Since $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, $(a,b)=(\pm 1,0)$ or $(a,b)=(0,\pm 1)$ thus $a+ib\in \{\pm 1,\pm i\}$. Conversely, it is clear that $\pm 1, \pm i$ are units therefore the units of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are  $\pm 1, \pm i$.

Comment: Your reasoning for what the units of Gaussian integers $\mathbb Z[i]$ is correct, but the Question asks us to prove something about the *nonunits*.  Perhaps you misread the Question?  Some further reasoning would be necessary to draw the requested conclusion.

Comment: @hardmath The present answer completely classifies units as those elements $a+bi$ such that $a^2+b^2=1$. Hence it also classifies nonunits as those elements such that $a^2+b^2\ne1$.

Comment: @egreg:  Although the OP does have tag "proof-verification", the structure of the Question is of that form.  So I feel the contribution you see in the above Answer is somewhat ephemeral and would be better stated as already found in the Question.