# Why is $1<|\text{Nm}_{K|\Bbb{Q}}(\beta)|< |\text{Nm}_{K|\Bbb{Q}}(\alpha)|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field. Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be its ring of integers.  Say $\alpha\in \mathcal{O}_K$ is not irreducible, then $\alpha=\beta\gamma$ where these are not units, Neukirchs text 'Algebraic Number Theory' page $16$ says that:
$$1<|\text{Nm}_{K|\Bbb{Q}}(\beta)|< |\text{Nm}_{K|\Bbb{Q}}(\alpha)|$$

Why is this so? I know the following two ways of defining the norm 1) let each $x\in L$ correspond to an endomorphism of $K$-vector spaces: $$T_x:L\to L,\quad a\mapsto xa.$$$\text{Nm}_{K|\Bbb{Q}}(\alpha)=\text{Det}(T_\alpha)$.

2) $\text{Nm}_{K|\Bbb{Q}}(\alpha)=\prod_{\sigma\in\text{Aut}_{\Bbb Q}(K)}\sigma\alpha.$

---

Not really sure how to begin. I know that the norm takes me into $\Bbb Q$, but I am not sure what is taken to $1$ or if anything can be taken to less than $1$, or why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element $\alpha$ has norm $\pm 1$ if and only if it is a unit in the ring of integers. Hence every non-unit $\gamma$ satisfies $|Nm(\gamma)|>1$.
Hence we have $1<|Nm(\beta)|$ and
$$
|Nm(\alpha)|=|Nm(\beta\gamma)|=|Nm(\beta)Nm(\gamma)|=|Nm(\beta)|\cdot |Nm(\gamma)|>|Nm(\beta)|. 
$$

Comment: The first part only demonstrates that for a non-unit $\gamma$ we have $|\text{Nm}(\gamma)|\ne 1$ right? How do you bound it from below?

Comment: I'm confused. The norm always takes an algebraic integer to an actual integer? If it's a norm for $L|K$, then I have for $a\in L$ that $\text{Nm}_{L|K}(a)\in K$ right?

Comment: The norm is an element in $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{Q}}=\Bbb{Z}$, the ring of integers of $\Bbb{Q}$. Remember, for a field extension $K/F$, the norm is  a map from $\mathcal{O}_K\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_F$.

Comment: You are welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint::** keep in mind that norm is multiplicative

Comment: With that I can deduce that $\text{Nm}_{K|\Bbb{Q}}(a)=1\iff a$ is a unit. If I can deduce that the norm of a non-unit has magnitude not less than $1$, then the result follows, how do I show this?